# How to index e-commerce products in Google using Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If I have an e-commerce or social network, is there any difference what to use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`? In order for it to be indexed by Google after the publication of a product on the e-commerce or the publication of a post on the social network?

Or are these methods in no way related to indexing?

I'm interested in how to properly index products using Next.js

Before Next.js, to create an indexable SPA https://ncov.dev I used `React` + `Express` and in google for `site:ncov.dev` I see my 3 pages with indexed content.

But how to implement this using Next.js? Do I need a `custom server` from the documentation or can I use the `SSR` itself?

Comment: did you find out ?

Comment: @Pengin yes, next js api routes + ssr

Comment: why would you need API routes, if you use getServerSideProps you can do anything there that API routes can do, right?